# computer going into gnu grub when removeable media is not plugged in

Tags: ubuntu, grub

i tried installing dualboot ubuntu onto a micro sd card and now when it is not plugged in my computer boots into gnu grub. when i type `exit` it says "checking media presence" before saying "a bootable device has not been detected" the computer works fine with the sd card plugged in. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you installed GRUB onto the HDD's MBR, but the `/boot` partition with GRUB's configuration and supplementary files is on the SD card.

You have to fix boot from within the system that was installed on the HDD and install GRUB into SD's MBR for it to not touch the HDD's MBR.

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: I don't know, you provided absolutely no information about the other systems that you have on a computer, how it boots (MBR, EFI, and so on). I answered the question that you asked, not the one you had in your mind.